# DJANGO - close two collapse buttons with one

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

I have a little problem with the collapse buttons in my django template, here is what I have :

[image 1 (button 1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/023J7.png)

when I click on the button, a second column is created on the table, with another button :

[image 2 (buttons 1 and 2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nd9O4.png)

and this second button create a third column when clicked :

[image 3 (buttons 1 and 2, and column 3)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoKBm.png)

The problem is that I want to "close" the columns 2 and 3 when i click on the button 1 (to make it come back like the first image), but it only close the 2nd column and the third stay displayed (I want my button 1 to close the two columns) :

[image 4 (button 1 and column 3)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDmnM.png)

Here is my code :

```
<tr>
  <td bgcolor="#FFEC00">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn btn-primary float-center" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#button1">Button 1</button>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr id="button1" class="collapse">
  <td bgcolor="#00FF00">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn btn-primary float-center" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#button2">Button 2</button>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr id="button2" class="collapse">
  <td bgcolor="#00C9FF">Hello</td>
</tr>
```

Does somebody know how can I do that ?

Comment: Please can you also share your javascript code?

Comment: @MattEllen I didn't do any Javascript, I'm using django and Python
here is the only javascript file I found :
`$(function () {

  // Ajout style bootstrap sur tous les élements de formulaire
  $("input:not([type='checkbox']),select,textarea").addClass("form-control");
  $("input[type='checkbox']").addClass("form-control-input");
  $("input[type='hidden']").parent(".form-group").hide()
  // Déclenchement des tooltips
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();

  $(document).on('select2:open', () => {
    document.querySelector('.select2-search__field').focus();
  });
})`

Comment: How are you hiding/showing the table cells if you're not using javascript?